# Line Graph Overlaying bar graph in base r

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have written the following code below. I would like to overlay a bar graph with a line graph. The code I have does it all but with just one problem. I would like the points on the line graph to be in the center of the bar graph, i.e. they should shift to the left a little bit. where Im I missing it? If this can be done in ggplot as well I would be happy too. but even base r would do

```
par(mai = c ( 1 , 2, 1, 1), omi = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
yy <- c(31,31,31,50,50,61,69,75,80,88,94,101,108,115,121,124,125,125,125,126,127)
name1 <- c ("15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35")
xx <- barplot(yy, ylab = "", names.arg = name1, ylim = c(0, 140),col="steelblue")
text(xx, yy + 3, labels = as.character(yy),srt=45)
mtext(2,text="",line=2)
par(new = T)
xx2 <- c(15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35)
yy2 <-   c(379,474,579,725,922,1181,1473,1846,2316,2962,3688,4786,6069,7605,9504,10680,11074,11074,11074,11483,11484)
plot(xx2, yy2, xlim = c(14, 36), ylim = c(0, 14000),type ="n" , axes = F, xlab ="",  ylab ="",col="blue",main="")
lines(xx2, yy2, lwd = 2,col="red",lty=1)
points(xx2, yy2, pch = 18, cex = 1,col="red")
text(xx2, yy2 + 4 , labels = as.character(yy2),srt=90)
par(new = T)
par(mai = c ( 1 , 1, 1, 1))
axis(2)
mtext(2,text="",line=2.5)
mtext("",side=1,col="black",line=2)
grid()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have different x scale due to the different margins of the two plots.

Unless you want to find xx2 by hand... another solution to consider is to use a right y axis instead.

```
yy <- c(31,31,31,50,50,61,69,75,80,88,94,101,108,115,121,124,125,125,125,126,127)
name1 <- c ("15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35")
xx <- barplot(yy, ylab = "", names.arg = name1, ylim = c(0, 140),col="steelblue")
text(xx, yy + 3, labels = as.character(yy),srt=45)
mtext(2,text="",line=2)
par(new = T)
yy2 <-   c(379,474,579,725,922,1181,1473,1846,2316,2962,3688,4786,6069,7605,9504,10680,11074,11074,11074,11483,11484)
plot(xx+0.5, yy2, "l", lwd = 2,col="red",lty=1, 
     axes=F, ylim=c(0, 14000), xlim=c(min(xx), max(xx)+1))
points(xx+0.5, yy2, pch = 18, cex = 1,col="red")
axis(4)
text(xx+0.5, yy2 + 4 , labels = as.character(yy2),srt=90)
```

[image: double plot]

Answer (score 1):

It can be quote tricky to get things to line up if you use `barplot` and a standard `plot()`. I recommend only calling `plot` once. In order to do this, you will need to rescale your `yy2` values to the same scale as `yy`. Here's how you might do that

```
par(mai = c ( 1 , 2, 1, 1), omi = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
yy <- c(31,31,31,50,50,61,69,75,80,88,94,101,108,115,121,124,125,125,125,126,127)
name1 <- c ("15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35")

#draw bar plot
xx <- barplot(yy, ylab = "", names.arg = name1, ylim = c(0, 140),col="steelblue")
text(xx, yy + 3, labels = as.character(yy),srt=45)
mtext(2,text="",line=2)

xx2 <- xx #c(15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35)
yy2 <-   c(379,474,579,725,922,1181,1473,1846,2316,2962,3688,4786,6069,7605,9504,10680,11074,11074,11074,11483,11484)

#transform data
yy2tx <- yy2/14000 * max(pretty(yy))

#draw line data
lines(xx2, yy2tx, lwd = 2,col="red",lty=1)
points(xx2, yy2tx, pch = 18, cex = 1,col="red")
text(xx2, yy2tx, labels = as.character(yy2),srt=90)

#draw axis for transformed data
par(mai = c ( 1 , 1, 1, 1))
axis(2, at=pretty(c(0,14000))/14000*max(pretty(yy)), labels=pretty(c(0,14000)))
grid()
```

This produces the following plot

[image]