# Align grid in secundary y axis - base plot R

Tags: r, graph, yaxis

I've been trying to display data with two different y axis range values. This [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580514/line-graph-overlaying-bar-graph-in-base-r) was very helpful in doing this with `barplot`:

```
# data 1
yy <- c(30,45,60,100,110,90,80,50,20,10,10,15)
name1 <- month.abb
xx <- barplot(yy, ylab = "", names.arg = name1,col="steelblue", ylim = c(0,120))

# data 2
par(new = T)
yy2 <- c(20,21,21,22,23,23.5,22,20,19,19,18,19)
plot(xx + 0.5, yy2, "l", ylim = c(18,24), lwd = 2,col="red", lty=1, 
     axes=F, xlim=c(min(xx), max(xx)+1))
points(xx + 0.5, yy2, pch = 18, cex = 1,col="red")
axis(4)
box()

# example grid
abline(h = 18)
### abline 18 through 23
abline(h = 24)
```

resulting in this output

[image]

I wonder how can I align the grids between y axis. I guess stretching the secundary axis to the top and bottom of the box could do it but I can't figure it out how to do that stretching. Any advice?

---

**EDIT.** Looking for a nice way of putting a legend I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55254018/creating-a-common-legend-for-bar-plot-and-line) response, which I think is very straightfoward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `plot` adds an extra 4% all sides of the plot range. `barplot` does not do this. That is why your your two axes do not line up. You can turn off the extra added space by using the argument `yaxs="i"`. Also,  instead of using `abline` many times,  I added the horizontal lines using `grid`. Putting this together, I get:

```
xx <- barplot(yy, ylab = "", names.arg = name1,col="steelblue", ylim = c(0,120))

# data 2
par(new = T)
yy2 <- c(20,21,21,22,23,23.5,22,20,19,19,18,19)
plot(xx + 0.5, yy2, "l", ylim = c(18,24), lwd = 2,col="red", lty=1, 
     axes=F, xlim=c(min(xx), max(xx)+1), yaxs="i")
points(xx + 0.5, yy2, pch = 18, cex = 1,col="red")
axis(4)
box()

grid(nx=1, ny=6, lty=1, col="black")
```

[image]